# Why does authentication check return true in Postman but return false on the browser?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I can't figure out why `dd(Auth::check());` returns `true` in Postman but returns false when trying to logout on the browser.

In the header, I'm making a `POST` request containing the headers required in order for `true` to be returned in my frontend code - exactly how I'm doing it Postman.

So why's it that it returns `false` on the browser but returns `true` in the Postman even though I'm doing the exact same thing?

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated :)

[image]

Here's frontend code:

```
const logout = () => {
    const headers = {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    };

    axios.post('http://website.test/api/logout', {headers})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Here's backend code:

```
public function logout() {
    dd(Auth::check());
}
```

Here's api.php

**Note:**

**When running `dd(Auth::check());` - it always returns `false` when it's OUTSIDE of the `middleware('auth:api');`.
However, when running `dd(Auth::check());` - it always returns `{message: "Unauthenticated."}` when it's INSIDE of the `middleware('auth:api');`.**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
   Route::post('/logout', [RegisterController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

Comment: Hey, the signature for post is `axios.post(url, data, config)`  your headers will go in the 3 place `axios.post(url, data, { headers: headers })`

Comment: @JuanEizmendi but there's no data for me send - only thing required is the header.

Comment: null sould work

Comment: @JuanEizmendi omg thank you so much, it worked!!

Comment: Method signature don't know about your needs..

Comment: Use `postman code generator` and generate Nodejs Axios code. probably some headers are different.
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/